# Reading an element's height property as a string with alert()

Tags: javascript, html

This is pretty rudimentary, but I want to know how I can access a property like height as a string. The mouseover alert here simply returns "undefined" (and saying height.value in the alert doesn't help either):

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="wut" align="center" height="10" onmouseover="alertheight()">
    hi.
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function alertheight() {
        alert(document.getElementById("wut").height);
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always put your `<script>` tags inside either the `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because most HTML elements do not have a height property (and those that have may not necesarely indicate the height in pixel). So the height attribute you added to the div-tag is ignored by the browser. Use css styles to define the heights of `div`'s and other elements:

```
<div id="wut" align="center" style="height: 10px" onmouseover="alertheight()">
```

What I guess you are looking for however is likely `clientHeight` and similar properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight

Comment: @Rujiel: If this is what you were looking for, please mark this answer as the answer. (Click the check-mark, just under the voting buttons.)